# How to download the image to the client-side storage by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, api

I am trying to put the functionality, where when the user clicks on image it gets downloaded to their computer, What i am trying to do is, i am fetching the images from an pixabay api into my website, where the user is able to look at the picture and by one click it gets downloaded to their local storage **not by right clicking and save image but just by left click**. How am I supposed to do that? Here is my code for fetching the api

```
$.ajax({
                url: "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+apikey+"&q="+term+"&image_type=photo&per_page=50",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(responseText){
                    
                var photos = responseText;
                   
                    var str = "";
                    for(let i = 0; i<photos.hits.length; i++){
                        str+="<div class='box'><img src=" + photos.hits[i].webformatURL + "></div>";
                    }
                    $("#photo-list").html(str);
```

I have tried the Download here. But this is not gonna work because the file do not belong to same origin. How can i make this work.

Answer (score 0):

use download attribute of anchor  tag

```
str+="<div class='box'>
             <a href= " + photos.hits[i].webformatURL + " download>
                   <img src=" + photos.hits[i].webformatURL + ">
             </a>
       </div>";
```

you can even specify the name of file which you want to download just assign name to the download attribute

```
<a href="path to your file" download="filename"> <img src="image path"> </a>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! i have tried this but that takes me to the new link but the image is not getting downloaded by clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) :

**Download** only works for **same-origin URLs**, or the **blob:** and **data:** schemes.

-If the Content-Disposition header has different information from the download attribute, resulting behavior may differ:

-If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute.

-If the header specifies a disposition of inline, Chrome, and Firefox 82 and later, prioritize the attribute and treat it as a download. Firefox versions before 82 prioritize the header and will display the content inline.

**what we can learn from that, you can download an image from your website coming from another origin**

for that you need to download image to your server before making it available to download from your website then you can use the download attribute to easily make it downloadable:

*This is wrong :*

```
<a href='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg' download>

<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg"/>
</a>
```

**That is right:**

```
<a href='https://mywebiste.com/path/to/images/myimage.svg' download>

<img src="https://mywebiste.com/path/to/images/myimage.svg"/>
</a>
```